# Call Method on object if Object Exists

Tags: ruby

Is there a more elegant way of writing this?

```
@on_connection_callback.call() if @on_connection_callback
```

It's having to reference @on_connection_callback twice that's irking me.

Answer (score 2):

you may write this as

```
@on_connection_callback.call() rescue nil
```

Comment: Rescuing blindly like that can create very hard to find problems.

Answer (score 2):

I like things like the ["andand" gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) which allows:

```
@on_connection_callback.andand.call()
```

There are other options, like various `try` implementations.

Answer (score 1):

```
@on_connection_callback.instance_eval{call if self}
```

Or

```
->p{p.call if p}.call(@on_connection_callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@on_connection_callback.call() if @on_connection_callback
```

is fine, and is actually the fastest way to test. I recently did a [benchmark test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382053/128421) here proving that the above is slightly faster than:

```
@on_connection_callback && @on_connection_callback.call()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this little [gem](https://github.com/sevenmaxis/tryit):

```
tryit { @on_connection_callback.call() }
```